# Avoid copying code for a lot of buttons

Tags: swift

Edit on my question:

Grimxn, I made a subclass and can see it works, because of the borderWidth and color. But I still have a couple of questions on how to add my function:

1. Should I code "func textField(textField: UITextField" or "func textField(textField: MyCustomTextField" ?
2. What should I do with "if textField == numberField01 {" ?
3. How do I 'call this' from the ViewController code ?

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var numberField01: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var numberField02: MyCustomTextField!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   numberField01.delegate = self
   numberField01.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
   numberField02.delegate = self
   numberField02.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
   ```

   }

   ```
   class MyCustomTextField: UITextField {
   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
       self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5

       func textField(textField: UITextField,
           shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
           replacementString string: String)
           -> Bool {
               var result = true
               var prospectiveText = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
               prospectiveText = prospectiveText.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
               if textField == numberField01 {
                   if count(string)>0 {
                       let disallowedCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "0123456789").invertedSet
                       let replacementStringIsLegal = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(disallowedCharacterSet) == nil
                       let resultingStringLengthIsLegal = count(prospectiveText) <= 4
                       let scanner = NSScanner(string: prospectiveText)
                       let resultingTextIsNumeric = scanner.scanDecimal(nil) && scanner.atEnd
                       result = replacementStringIsLegal && resultingStringLengthIsLegal && resultingTextIsNumeric
                   }
               }
               return result
       }
   }

   }
   ```

   Original question:
   The following code is working fine for one textfield (numberField01). It makes sure the input is decimal only, places a decimal point, and prevents a user to paste in a non decimal string. But I have a lot more buttons... (numberField02 and up). How can I handle more buttons, without just copying my code for each button?

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var numberField01: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var numberField02: UITextField!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   numberField01.delegate = self
   numberField01.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
   numberField02.delegate = self
   numberField02.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
   super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }

   // Tap background to add decimal point and defocus keyboard

   @IBAction func userTappedBackground(sender: AnyObject) {
   for view in self.view.subviews as! [UIView] {
     if let textField = view as? UITextField {
       if count(numberField01.text) > 0 {
           var numberString = numberField01.text
           numberString = numberString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
           var numberFromString = Double(numberString.toInt()!) / 100
           numberField01.text = String(format:"%.2f", numberFromString)
       }
       textField.resignFirstResponder()
     }
   }
   }

   func textField(textField: UITextField,
       shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
       replacementString string: String)
       -> Bool {
           var result = true
           var prospectiveText = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
           prospectiveText = prospectiveText.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
           if textField == numberField01 {
               if count(string)>0 {
                   let disallowedCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "0123456789").invertedSet
                   let replacementStringIsLegal = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(disallowedCharacterSet) == nil
                    let resultingStringLengthIsLegal = count(prospectiveText) <= 4
                   let scanner = NSScanner(string: prospectiveText)
                   let resultingTextIsNumeric = scanner.scanDecimal(nil) && scanner.atEnd
                   result = replacementStringIsLegal && resultingStringLengthIsLegal && resultingTextIsNumeric
               }
           }
           return result
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Why not just create a method that returns a button that has all the common functionality?

Comment: can you explain that a little bit more, Maxqueue? or give me a clue where i can find an example? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something similar to the following:

```
    Button GetButtonCommonFeatures(Button myButton)
    {
        Write common code here....
        e.g. myButton.delegate = self;...
        return myButton;
    }
```

Then call your method for each button. Lets take numberField01 for example. You will include the code in the method that applies to every button.

```
    numberField01 = GetButtonCommonFeatures(numberField01);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Grimxn. Can you give me an example? And what are the advantages / diasadvantages compared to the Solution above? Thanks!